# LINQ anonym object with result to delimited string (LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method)

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to get a ; demlimited string of all the relatives that a person has.
Four tables are involved:

USERTAB 
PERSON
PERSON_RELATION
RELATION_TAB

Query

```
from u in USERTAB
select new
{
    Person = from p in PERSON where p.USERID == u.USERID
       select new
        {
          PNo = p.NO,
          Name = p.NAME
          Relatives = (from r in PERSON_RELATION where r.PSEQ == p.PSEQ select new
          {
            Description = (from rel in RELATION_TYPE where rel.TYPE_SEQ == r.TYPE_SEQ select rel.DESCRIPTION).ToArray() //(or also tried .ToString())
          })                                     
        }
}
```

I'd like the Description field to be a ";" delimited list of all the relatives a user (person) has.

Using a ToString on my Relatives object it only fails runtime with. LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method

Example: Description = "Father, Brother, Cousin"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be clear about what parts of your query get translated to SQL to run on the server, and what parts run in your local application. The key is to construct a simple query to retrieve all the data, then use `.AsEnumerable()` to ensure that the remaining transformations don't get translated to SQL, and finally transform the data into a form useful for you. Something like

```
var query =
    from u in USERTAB
    select new
    {
        Person =
            from p in PERSON
            where p.USERID == u.USERID
            select new
            {
                PNo = p.NO,
                Name = p.NAME
                Relatives =
                    from r in PERSON_RELATION
                    where r.PSEQ == p.PSEQ
                    select new
                    {
                        Description =
                            from rel in RELATION_TYPE
                            where rel.TYPE_SEQ == r.TYPE_SEQ
                            select pos.DESCRIPTION
                    }
            }
        }
    };

var enumerable =
    from u in query.AsEnumerable()
    select new
    {
        Person =
            from p in u.Person
            select new
            {
                PNo = p.PNo,
                Name = p.Name
                Relatives =
                    string.Join(", ",
                        from r in p.Relatives
                        from d in r.Description
                        select d.Description)
            }
        }
    };
```

should do the trick.

Comment: It returns: This method is not supported against a materialized query result.

Comment: @Kman Are you using a simple `foreach` loop on the result, or something more complicated? If something more complicated, don't forget to store the results in memory somewhere first using, for example, `enumerable.ToList()`. If you get that exception even then, I'll take a closer look and try to come up with a fully working minimal example.

Comment: I get this to work if I use LinqToSQL (running towards a MSSQL database). However, using LinqToEntity towards another database (Sybase) I get the not supported against a materialized query result. It seems that the problem is located in the EF data provider. Would there be any other approaches that I might try?

Comment: But your solution is solving my initial question, so I'll mark it as an answer. Thanx

Comment: @Kman I'll take a look and see if I can get this working with EF with MSSQL (I have no Sybase here, but I do use EF). It'll take some time though.

Comment: @Kman Have taken a closer look, it'll work if you change `from r in PERSON_RELATION` to `from r in PERSON_RELATION.AsEnumerable()` (and similarly for the other subqueries, just not the top one), it breaks otherwise because the compiler / EF thinks the query result should contain nested yet separate queries, instead of one single result set.

Answer (score 0):

This should work: write an extension method for strings of array, like so:

```
public static ToCsv(this string[] strings)
{
    return String.Join("," strings);
}
```

Then just tack `.ToCsv()` at the end of your `.ToArray()` call above, and it should do the trick!

Comment: That would just result in a different "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method ..." exception. `.ToCsv` cannot be run on the server, so shouldn't be part of a query's expression, it should be run on the client.

Comment: Right, I forgot this was L2E. It will not be able to compile the query. I guess the only way then is to load the data in memory using multiple queries, then SELECT a result from them using in-memory LINQ which can use extension methods such as this one.